# How does multi-processing in python increase the execution time?

Tags: python, python-3.x, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

I have tried simple piece of python code containing two for-loops using multi-processing pool.

First I set the pool=1, total execution time was= 22211 ms.

while for pool=40, total execution time for each of 40 processes was=

Time taken: 24045, Time taken: 24047, Time taken: 24072, Time taken: 24096, Time taken: 24117, Time taken: 24120, Time taken: 24158, Time taken: 24165, Time taken: 24215, Time taken: 24346, Time taken: 24395, Time taken: 24499, Time taken: 24619, Time taken: 24860, Time taken: 27499, Time taken: 31077, Time taken: 32225, Time taken: 33708, Time taken: 37483, Time taken: 37516, Time taken: 37520, Time taken: 37532, Time taken: 37555, Time taken: 37575, Time taken: 37579, Time taken: 37590, Time taken: 37636, Time taken: 37639, Time taken: 37671, Time taken: 37672, Time taken: 37715, Time taken: 37780, Time taken: 37799, Time taken: 37805, Time taken: 37821, Time taken: 37832, Time taken: 37849, Time taken: 37958, Time taken: 38080, Time taken: 38086 (all time in ms.)

**System info**: It was ran on machine of 56 CPU cores with hyper-threading.
My code is:

```
import time
from multiprocessing import Pool
def compute(da):
    start_time = int(round(time.time() * 1000))
    sum = 0
    for i in range(10000):
        for j in range(50000):
            sum = sum + j
    print (sum)
    print ('Time taken: '+ str(int(round(time.time() * 1000))-start_time))

#start_time = int(round(time.time() * 1000))
data1 = ['1']
data40 = ['1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10','11','12,'13','14','15','16','17','18','19','20','21','22','23','24','25','26','27','28','29','30','31','32','33','34','35','36','37','38','39','40]
# FOR ONE PROCESS
p = Pool(1)
p.map(compute, data1)
# FOR 40 PROCESS
p = Pool(40)
p.map(compute, data40)
```

As we could see the execution time increases gradually from 24045(1st process) to 38086(40th process).

I would like to know, Why does this happen?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: but the final result is still faster right? (that is if you divide the total time by 40)

Comment: Any parallel process still has a non-parallel part.

The only explanation here is: memory bottleneck. If you were using a real code, you'd hit disk IO bottleneck, network bottleneck ...

Here, even in this simple example, your processes still have to access the memory (to write `sum`, to write the loop counter). So the more processes are running, the higher the bottleneck is.

But on my machine, with 40 processes, it's globally 5 times faster (I don't have a lot of CPUs), so don't worry about that, it's still worth using the multiprocessing module.

Comment: The timing mentioned is taken by each process to execute the same piece of code. Plus the timing that I have taken is from as soon as Compute function gets called to when it ends. So definitely it looks to be overhead of multi-processing. Talking about memory bottleneck, then I have 256 GB of RAM, and memory is not bottleneck. Other than memory, this piece of code does not use any other resources like disk or network.I have 56 cores available, while I launch only 40 processes.This time increases when I pool 50 processes.I am not able to understand this behavior of python multi-processing.